# Fabric error: QuartzCore (CA::Layer::set_bounds(CA::Rect const&, bool))

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, quartz-core

In my project I'm getting a lot of crashes for

> QuartzCore CA::Layer::set_bounds(CA::Rect const&, bool)

From Fabric I get the following message.

> Heads Up! CALayerInvalidGeometry; CALayer bounds contains NaN: [...] 
>   Details:
>   This crash is likely due to a division by zero when applying a transform to a view or layer. Setting the 'CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE' environment variable in Xcode can help pinpoint the root cause. Check out the references below for more details.
>   External resources:
>   Crash occurring because “CALayer bounds contains NaN: [nan 0; nan 15.1]
>   'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer bounds contains NaN' exception
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]' #15

**How can I solve this crash problem?**

Below I share the screenshot of the crash I got from Fabric.
[image: Fabric screenshot]

Below I share the class of the **UserDefaults-AppLocale.swift** in my project.

```
extension UserDefaults {
    private enum Key : String {
        case languageCode = "LanguageCode"
        case regionCode = "RegionCode"
    }

    static var languageCode: String? {
        get {
            let defs = UserDefaults.standard
            return defs.string(forKey: Key.languageCode.rawValue)
        }
        set(value) {
            let defs = UserDefaults.standard
            if let value = value {
                defs.set(value, forKey: Key.languageCode.rawValue)
                return
            }
            defs.removeObject(forKey: Key.languageCode.rawValue) // Line 29
        }
    }

    static var regionCode: String? {
        get {
            let defs = UserDefaults.standard
            return defs.string(forKey: Key.regionCode.rawValue)
        }
        set(value) {
            let defs = UserDefaults.standard
            if let value = value {
                defs.set(value, forKey: Key.regionCode.rawValue)
                return
            }
            defs.removeObject(forKey: Key.regionCode.rawValue)
        }
    }
}
```

It's **line 29** on this Fabric.

```
defs.removeObject(forKey: Key.languageCode.rawValue)
```

Comment: This is very confusing. The error appears clearly related to the rendering of a layer in your view, due to a NaN appearing somewhere in the definition of the bounds. But line 29 relates to your application state - I.e a change in your user defaults. Are you rendering the view based on these defaults (in a table view or some such)? Does the error occur when that dictionary is emptied?

Comment: @Marcus Yes, I use these defaults too much in order to find the application language. Like this:  if Locale.current.languageCode! == "en" { .. } If it were empty, did not you give the error in these lines?